# How to implement django otp?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I was looking at [django-otp](https://django-otp-official.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module and want to implement it in my project. But I am facing several problems.

1) According to docs(the method they have given in docs), there are three level of authentication: `Anonymous`, `Authenticated` and `Authenticated + Verified`. If a user is already already authenticated via django's authentication system only then he will be asked for otp verification (Two way authentication).

Now i want to skip it and authenticate/verify user only via otp. Instead of login prompt user will enter a phone number and will recieve a otp for verification.(I want to bypass django's authentication).

2) Also i want to use [otp_required](http://django-otp-official.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auth.html#django_otp.decorators.otp_required) only on selected pages. i.e. i will have both anonymous and verified users on my website.

3) I couldn't find any example regarding the implementation.

My question is how to implement it in my current scenario.

EDIT:  Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home',
    'django_otp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_static',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: This is pretty far outside the intent of django-otp. It sounds like you want to write a custom Django authentication backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own Class Based View mixins, something like the [LoginRequired mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

```
class AuthenticationVerificationMixin(AccessMixin):
    """
    CBV mixin which verifies that the current user is authenticated,
    and has a placeholder for checking if user verified.
    """
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return self.handle_no_permission()
        elif not request.user.is_verified():
            # If you need a verification logic it will go here,
            # for example here's a redirect if you're not verified...
            # return redirect_to_login(self.request.get_full_path(), '/verify/'), self.get_redirect_field_name())
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and then add these mixins to your views like

```
class MyView(AuthenticationVerificationMixin, TemplateView):
    ...
```